# What's happening when reversing a list with append in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, reverse

I don't quite understand whats happening the this code:

```
reverse2([],[]).
reverse2([H|T],R):- reverse2(T,R2), append(R2,[H],R).
```

It doesn't make sense to me that we are recursing before appending.

Could someone explain it how each element H is being appending after the base case is reached?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The recursion is on the tail of the list. Consider the list `[1,2,3]`. The first rule doesn't match. The second rule matches, unifying `H = 1` and `T = [2,3]`. Then we call `reverse2([2,3], R2)`. Again, the first rule doesn't match. The second rule matches, unifying `H = 2` and `T = [3]`. You can see that recursion from here will eventually hit the first rule. Zooming back to the outermost call where `H = 1` and `T = [2, 3]`, we will wind up with `R2 = [3, 2]`. Then the append will occur, sticking `[1]` on the end.

You may find it instructive to do a sample query like this:

```
?- trace, reverse2([1,2,3], X).
```

This will show you how the query unfolds and the bindings of each variable.

The way to think about recursive functions is inductively. Look at the base case. The base case should be trivially true, and it is--the reverse of the empty list is indeed the empty list. Then look at the inductive case. Assuming that it works for a smaller list of size N, does it work for a list of size N+1? **Assume** it can reverse the tail of the list (size = N), and see that if that is true, appending the head to the end would make it work for N+1. That's all you need to believe for induction to work. If you believe those two things, you believe everything there is to believe and it will work for every input. So liberate yourself from the need to believe in any other steps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to build a little on Daniel's description, you could read the recursive clause:

```
reverse2([H|T], R) :- reverse2(T, R2), append(R2, [H], R).
```

As:

*`R` is the reverse of list `[H|T]` if `R2` is the reverse of `T`, and `R` is the list `[H]` appended to the end of list `R2`.*

Or, somewhat imperatively, as:

*To reverse a list, first reverse its tail, then append the head of the original list to that result*.

So in that description, the recursive goal of `reverse2(T, R2)` comes first.

The definition in this case is *depth first*. It's going to keep recursing until it hits the trivial base case, then return from each goal doing the appends:

```
(1) reverse2([1,2,3], R) :- reverse2([2,3], R2), append(R2, [1], R).
(2) reverse2([2,3], R) :- reverse2([3], R2), append(R2, [2], R).
(3) reverse2([3], R) :- reverse2([], R2), append(R2, [3], R).
(4) reverse2([], []).
```

Then the returns:

```
(3) reverse2([3], R) :- reverse2([], []), append([], [3], R). % R = [3]
(2) reverse2([2,3], R) :- reverse2([3], [3]), append([3], [2], R). % R = [3,2]
(1) reverse2([1,2,3], R) :- reverse2([2,3], [3,2]), append([3,2], [1], R).
```

Result:

```
reverse2([1,2,3], [3,2,1]).
```

As an aside, this is actually a fairly inefficient way to do a `reverse/2` predicate. And it has some issues if you do, `reverse(L, [1,2,3])` after it finds the first solution. It's interesting to note that if you swap the recursion and the `append/3` queries around:

```
reverse2([H|T], R) :- append(R2, [H], R), reverse2(T, R2).
```

This actually behaves better on `reverse2(L, [1,2,3])` but then has a problem after finding the first solution to `reverse2([1,2,3], L)`. The opposite of what happens with the case in which the recursive query comes first. With this definition, if the first argument is bound but not the second, it has the inefficiency of finding irrelevant possible solutions to the `append(R2, [H], R)` first when neither `R2` or `R` are initially bound before it finds the correct solution through the subsequent recursion. Then after finding that solution, it infinitely tries more irrelevant potential solutions emerging from backtracks to `append/3`.

If you look up the source code for `reverse/2` in the SWI Prolog implementation, it uses pure recursion and difference lists to overcome these shortcomings.